# PendingIntent does not invoke BroadcastReceiver of killed process

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm currently working on an app that uses an **IntentService**, that does some work and then sets up a **PendingIntent** to wake itself at some specified time.

My Problem is that the respective **static BroadcastReceiver** gets not invoked if the proccess is killed, but it does get invoked if I - for example - set *"android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"* in the intent-filter in my Manifest.

For killing the app I use a longpress on the back-button on my HTC Desire (2.3.7 CyanogenMod 7.2.0.1)  ;)

Here is my Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.jdev.myapp.service.MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >

        <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" /> </intent-filter>

        //Just Used as an example

        <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.jdev.myapp.REINITIALIZATION" /> </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.jdev.myapp.PROFILE_ENGAGED" /> </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.jdev.myapp.PROFILE_DISENGAGED" /> </intent-filter>

        //Some more custom Actions here

        <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data
                android:path="com.jdev.myapp"
                android:scheme="package" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I create my PendingIntents like that:

```
int Id;

Intent engaged = new Intent(Constants.PROFILE_ENGAGED);
//put some Extra

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), Id, engaged, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

After that I set it at the calculated time by using AlarmManager...

The whole app works nice as long as the process is alive. But if the process is killed - which actually should not be a problem, as the BroadcastReceiver just has to start the Service again, the Receiver gets not invoked, but as mentioned above by System stuff like *"android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"*.

According to the docs it actually should work:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and can thus call cancel() to remove it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Stop using "a longpress on the back-button on my HTC Desire". Whatever that does in your ROM mod is unscheduling your alarms, presumably. You can confirm this by examining the output of **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`**.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your tip. In the shell i find tons of facebook alarms, but no one with one of my actions...
It's the first time I am using adb actually. I set my App debuggable in the Manifest, reinstalled it, killed it and launched your command in the shell - did I miss something? Or is there an alternative, "cleaner" way to simulate the kill of my process? Apart from that I tried to catch the Intents with a second application, which also worked during the process of the sending app was alive...

Comment: "Or is there an alternative, "cleaner" way to simulate the kill of my process?" -- use DDMS. Highlight your process in the Devices tab and click the stop button.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Simulating a kill with the DDMS worked, the BroadcastReceiver got invoked! :) I guess your right with your assumption, I'll add that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CommonsWare pointed out, killing processes like that

> For killing the app I use a longpress on the back-button on my HTC Desire (2.3.7 CyanogenMod 7.2.0.1)

Seems to be very destructive, because it also - in my case - obviously removed the Alarms connected with my app, which was not intended.

To simulate your process is killed use

> **DDMS => higlight the process of your app => hit STOP**

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended -- the particular Cyanogenmod UI that you're using is equivalent to going into Settings / Apps / [detailed app info] and hitting the "force stop" button.  This puts the app back into its just-installed state, and in that state the app is not allowed to run without some direct user interaction.  "Stopped" apps like this deliberately do not receive broadcasts.